# Java stop the playing wav

Tags: java, loops, audio, wav

I am writing a program which needs to play a sound in a loop. If the sound is under 3 seconds long there is no problem, but if the sound is longer it doesn't play it even once.

```
private void sound() throws IOException {

    try {

        BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("src/Sounds/wow1.wav"));
        MD = BGM.getData();
        loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MGP.start(loop);

}

private void stop() {
    try {
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(loop);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```